# Woocommerce orders set payed after create

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

All of my woocommerce orders are automatically updated as Completed after create it, and never goes to redsys / sermepa gateway (throws an error).

When i choose Paypal I manage to the Paypal Gateway, but the order it's already Completed too, and I don't pay nothing!

Woocommerce version it's 2.6.8. Someone knows why that happends?

Thanks in advance and sorry my english :)

Answer (score 0):

Already solvented uninstalling other plugins, It seems Calendar Events Ticket plus it's messing with regular orders!